# Python - Download File Returned by Web Form Submission

Tags: python

*** Updated to clarify information from responses ***

There is a website my IT organization set up that allows us to submit a set of parameters to a web form, click on a "submit" button, and then it generates a .txt file of users provisioned to specified applications which is (at least using my current Chrome settings) automatically sent to the download folder.

In order to automate this process and get an updated list of users each week, I've been trying to write a python script that uses urllib (+ urllib2, requests, etc.) in order to submit the form and then grab the .txt file that is downloaded.

When I try running the code below...

---

```
import urllib, urllib2

url = 'my url'

values = {'param1' : 'response1', 
          'param2' : 'response2', 
          'param3' : 'response3'
          }


data = urllib.urlencode(values)          
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
data = response.read()
```

---

...it doesn't throw any errors, but I don't get any response either. I've checked all the likely paths that the file would download to and can't find anything.

And if I add something like...

```
with open('response.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

...then it just writes the source HTML for the page to the file; it doesn't actually grab the file generated by the query I'm essentially posting through the form.

---

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't saved the response to a file.

```
with open('response.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

That will save a file called response.txt to the directory you have run the script from. If you just want to check the contents of the response you can use:

```
print(data)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this just returns the HTML source for the web page to the text file. I need to actually grab the file that gets generated after I submit.

Comment: Is the HTML of the page with the form?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, no - the HTML of the page is not within the form / file generated by the request process. Also, in case it makes any difference, the file doesn't get generated until runtime since one of the input parameters is a query parameter; therefore there is typically about a 5-10 second delay before the .txt file is actually generated and the download of the file begins.